# how to convert simple string in to logical "if" validation statment in php

Tags: php

I have a string from database `([INDEX]>0):[INDEX],0`, Now I have a value of `$index`. How can i set that string in to IF condition in php like,

`([INDEX]>0):[INDEX],0`

```
$var='';
if($index>0){
 $var = $index;
} else {
 $var = 0;
}
```

there will also other conditions like

```
`[AGE] > 18:([AGE]-15)/1000`

 that will make validation like

$newage = 0;
if($age > 18){
  $newage = ($age-15)/1000
}
```

How can i manage it ?

Comment: Did you try something on your own so far? Please share your code with us!

Comment: Why, in the first example, are you assigning the result to `$var`, but in the second example you are assigning it to the variable that was used in the condition (`$age`).  Is there some logic/criteria for this?  Also, what is the significance of the `0` in `[INDEX],0`?  What would the desired result be if that was `[INDEX],5`?

Comment: 0 will set is in 'else' statement, I edited question @PatrickQ

Comment: probably "database" is designed for some framework. Do You have some knowledge?

Comment: so the format is `condition:if-true,if-false'? And if there's no comma then no else?

Comment: @PaulHodges yes exactly

Comment: Where are the variables used in the conditions being defined?  Can you provide code that shows the context for where this will be used?